# Error WordPress REST API V2 call with Vue.js

Tags: wordpress, xmlhttprequest, vue.js, axios, wp-api

I am getting the following error, when I make a call to WP REST API with Vue.js and axios.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://my-wordpress-site.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts.
>   The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://null' that is not equal to the supplied origin. 
>   Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

When I use Postman with GET method, it is working correctly.

Where is the problem?

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    posts: [],
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.getPosts()
  },
  methods: {
    getPosts: function() {
      var app = this

      axios.get('http://my-wordpress-site.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts')
      .then(function (response) {
        app.posts = response.data.title.rendered
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
      })
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="section">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="post in posts">{{ post }}</li>
    </ul>
    <h3></h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's a CORS related issue. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: @potray I'm sure. But I cannot come up with a solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it by changing a line in wp-includes/rest-api.php file, 
 in rest_send_cors_headers() function:

`header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`

Comment: Editing WordPress core does not seem like a viable solution.

Comment: I admire your comment but it's a small fix not solving the problem. If the wordpress gets updated the whole thing would go away. That's why I put a down vote 